# MediaWiki: Adding a new tab to a page

Tags: tabs, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

In MediaWiki when you create a new page, I see the tabs at the top of the page named Page and Discussion. I'm not real familiar with MediaWiki, but I wanted to know if you could add an additional tab next to Discussion that links to a discussion page or links to a new page.

Not sure I'm communicating this correctly, but really, I want to add additional pages to the same namespace and have a tab at the top to get to the page.

[Page] [Discussion] [Apples] [Oranges] [Pears]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the hacky way like the [English Wikinews does](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Comments.js):

```
        var res = mw.util.addPortletLink(
            'p-namespaces',
            url,
            OpinionTabName,
            'ca-comments',
            OpinionTabTooltip
        );
```

Or there are supposedly fancier solutions, whose status I don't know, like the [DynamicTabs extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicTabs) or [hooking into SkinTemplateNavigation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_add.2Fremove_tabs_throughout_my_wiki.3F) as the FAQ says.

By the way this is a somehow hot topic, there's even a ["Custom inter-namespace tabs" RfC](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/Custom_inter-namespace_tabs) which you may want to comment on if that's what you're trying to do.